# Sending a List of complex Objects through Http Params to a Spring MVC Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, http-parameters

My POJO

```
public class SearchCriteria {
    private String key;
    private String operation;
    private Object value;

    default constructor, parameters constructor, setters and getters....
}
```

My RestController method signature.

```
@GetMapping("/subscribers")
public ResponseEntity<List<SubscriberDTO>> getAllSubscribers(Pageable pageable,
    @RequestParam(name = "lstSearchCriteria", required = false) List<SearchCriteria> lstSearchCriteria)
```

Now i want to be able to pass through HttpParams the List of SearchCriteria required by the getAllSubscribers() method.

I have tried a few different ways of doing it but either i take an:
  **Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' exception**

or **the list is null**

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Is your SearchCriteria class serializable?

Comment: No it's not.. is that a problem!?!? I have an overload method which i first made in which the List<SearchCriteria> is sent through the body... but i was told that practice was a bad practice and i should instead send List<SearchCriteria> through HttpParams. And the overload version where parameters are sent over body works just fine.. I sent them in Json format btw

Comment: It depends on how you add search parameters to url. The general way is to implement custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver and register it. But first consider that type conversion is automatically applied if the target method parameter type is not String and you can customize type conversion through a WebDataBinder or by registering Formatters with the FormattingConversionService. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-typeconversion

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your replies.

I took another approach which i would like that you guys comment if it's a valid one.

RestController method signature now:

```
 public ResponseEntity<List<SubscriberDTO>> getAllSubscribers(Pageable pageable,
    @RequestParam(name = "jsonSearchCriteriaList", required = false) String jsonSearchCriteriaList)
```

And through Jackson API i build up a List from a new Util class made for the purpose...

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<SearchCriteria>>(){});
```

And then everything works as expected!

What do you think?